# Database paid users and trial users in same table

Tags: database

If you had to design a database with paid users and trial users would you put them in the same table and differentiate between them with a field?  Or would you put them in two separate tables?

Or would you do the best of both worlds and put them in the same table but create two views 1) PaidUsers and 2) TrialUsers

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I would. What was the question?

Comment: There are 3 different options for the database design
1) Paid and Trial in the same table
2) Paid and Trial in different tables
3) Paid and Trial in the same table with Views to split them out into separate views.

Comment: One very important thing you're probably missing: the views has _nothing_ to do with your database design. Every time you query a view, the sql that is defining the view is also getting executed, thus, defining a view is _only_ useful if you use some query a lot in your app. But, since you only starting to design your db - you don't know which queries will be frequent, in other words, planing to create views in the beginning of db design don't make much sense.

Comment: Well I would commonly need to know if a user is a paid or trial user so I think it would end up being a common query, but I do appreciate your clarification to make sure design stays honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your paid users would probably be related to some additional data, but still have the same fieldset as non-paid, the correct way to do this is `[is-a]` approach:

**User** 
id 
username 
password 
fullname 
...

**Paiduser** 
user_id [`fk->User::id`] 
account_id 
.... 
[other addidional data]

**EDIT**: Now, the trial users will be all records in `User` that does not have entry in `Paiduser`. I'm assuming that Paiduser fieldset is a superset of the fieldset of a trial/normal user [User].

**EDIT 2**: To get a list of trial users, which are 'set difference' between `User` and `Paiduser`, the following sql should work:

```
select u.*
from (User as u
      join Paiduser as p on u.id<>p.user_id)
```

Comment: So then I assume you would also have a table called TrialUser?  So you think option #2.

Comment: I am trying to consider this design but since it is a new to new what is the general sql call to get the trial user?  Something like SELECT *  FROM User, PaidUser WHERE User.ID <> PaidUser.user_id;

Comment: Is this sql statement the same as yours just expressed differently? SELECT User.* FROM User, PaidUser WHERE User.ID <> PaidUser.user_id

Comment: I think I found a problem with your SQL statement or I am wondering if this is common.  If there are 10 users, 1 trial and 9 paid.  When you run your sql statement I get 9 rows returned because the 1 trial user doesn't equal each of the 9 paid users.  Is there a better way to express this sql so that I only receive the one trial user?  I would assume instead of the <> you would need to use something like "does not exist" but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: I believe the improved SQL should be SELECT ID FROM User WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT u.ID FROM User as u, PaidUser as p WHERE u.ID = p.User_ID)

Comment: Nope, I believe the `join` approach is the most efficient. 'does not exist' is achieved by <> match through join. With the subquery above you will issue 2 queries with intermediary data in memory. I haven't tested this but in theory I believe the join is the right way.

Comment: Yes please double check because when I am running the query on actual data in a database it it returning too many duplicates as I said before.  To clarify more, my new sql statement finds all of the paid users, and then takes the inverse which results in the trial user set.  Your sql uses <> but it really needs not exists.  Otherwise you will end up comping different users.  For example if the u.id is 1 and the p.user_id is 2 then these are not equal and they will return an entry but this isn't what we want here.  Your ideas were a great starting point for me but this is a subtle difference.

Comment: Yes! Sorry, i was in a haste. Your query with `not in` is the proper thing. It can be optimized like this: `SELECT ID FROM User WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT User_ID FROM PaidUser)`

Answer (score 1):

I just express some performance considerations in following opinions.

In single user query(ex. login check, or data retrieving for single user), there are not significant differences between these two strategies.

But if you need some statistic data, for example, one for paid users and another for trial users. And seperating to two tables may be a good idea.

Otherwise, if you need some statistic data whatever paid users or trial users, single table may be a good idea.

---

What if you need both of scenarios? Well, I think that would be a case which some common attributes exist between two kinds of users.

These common attributes should be put in one table, and dedicated attributes for particular users should be put in 'sub-table' inheriting from former table. Just as vonPetrushev said.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution may depend on database type. My experience is with MySQL and SQL Server. I've always put all users into a single table. Then differentiate as needed using fields. This could apply to paid/ unpaid or anything else. This solution meets 3NF standards and seems easier to me for maintenance etc. What reason would there be to use multiple tables?

Comment: The reason to split them into different tables is so the paid users don't get confused with the trial users by forgetting to check for the "Paid" field in the sql.

Comment: You're right assuming there is no additional information related to paid users, and there almost certainly is, account number being the most obvious possibility.

Comment: -1: db design has **absolutely nothing** do to with your choice of relational database: mysql, mssql, postgresql, sqlite - does not matter.

Comment: @vonPetrushev it does to the extent that some servers don't support certain features well or at all.

Comment: @Alex JL: this is why I was careful to include 'relational' before database: it goes without saying that it needs to support unique keys, foreign keys, transactions etc. MyISAM does not.